# Date ranking in Access SQL?

Tags: ms-access

I have a query pulling the last six months of data from a table which has a column, UseDates (so as of today in June, this table has dates for December 2011 through May 2012).

I wish to include a "rank" column that associates a 1 to all December dates, 2 to all January dates, etc -- up to 6 for the dates corresponding one month prior. If I were to open up this query a month from now, the 1 would then be associated with January, etc.

I hope this makes sense!

Example, if I ran the query right now

```
UseDate        Rank
12/31/2011     1
1/12/2012      2
...
5/23/2012      6
```

Example, if I ran the query in August:

```
UseDate        Rank
2/16/2012      1
3/17/2012      2
...
7/21/2012      6
```

Example, if I ran the query in March:

```
UseDate        Rank
9/16/2011      1
10/17/2011     2
...
2/24/2012      6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    UseDates,
    DateDiff("m", Date(), UseDates) + 7 AS [Rank]
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: I added some clarifying examples

Comment: Is there a way to make it dynamic so I don't have to hardcore a date into it? I might forget about it later

Comment: Oops. The hard-coded date was carried over from my testing.  Try the version as I corrected just now.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [month function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/month.php) for `UseDates` and subtract it from the result of [now](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/now.php) function. If it goes negative, just add 12. Also you may want to add 1 since you start with 1 and not 0. Apparently it should work for half a year date ranges. You'll get into trouble when you need to "rank" several years.

Comment: I am not sure this works -- but I have added some clarifying examples if this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can rank with a count.

```
SELECT 
   Table.ADate, 
   (SELECT Count(ADate) 
    FROM Table b 
    WHERE b.ADate<=Table.ADate) AS Expr1
FROM Table3;
```

You have to repeat any where statement in the subquery:

```
SELECT 
   Table.ADate, 
   (SELECT Count(ADate) 
    FROM Table b 
    WHERE b.ADate<=Table.ADate And Adate>#2012/02/01#) AS Expr1
FROM Table3
WHERE   Adate>#2012/02/01#
```